# iOS, interface builder bug with sizing classes and IBInspectables?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode7

I'm not sure whats going on, I'm pulling my hair out trying to workaround this, I'm trying to cater for different sizing classes in code to cater for some special cases using IBInspectables.

On the simulator the following code works as expected on iPad, iPhone 4 and iPhone 6+.

However in interface builder and preview only any / any and regular / regular work.

It seems like a bug ?
Or has anyone got any suggestions about an alternative approach which might work?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code
CGFloat l_borderWidth = self.AaBorderWidth; // 8.5
CGFloat l_cornerRadius = self.AaCornerRad; // 33
CGFloat l_shadHeight = self.AaShadHeight; // 15.1
CGFloat l_textYOffset = self.AaTextYOffset; // 6.1

if (self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact)
{
    if (self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact)
    {
        //iphone3.5 / 4 / 4.7 landscape
        l_borderWidth = self.CcBorderWidth;
        l_cornerRadius = self.CcCornerRad;
        l_shadHeight = self.CcShadHeight;
        l_textYOffset = self.CcTextYOffset;
    }
}

if (self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular)
{
    if (self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular)
    {
        //ipad landscape
        l_borderWidth = self.RrBorderWidth;
        l_cornerRadius = self.RrCornerRad;
        l_shadHeight = self.RrShadHeight;
        l_textYOffset = self.RcTextYOffset;
    }
    if (self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact)
    {
        //iphone6+
        l_borderWidth = self.RcBorderWidth;
        l_cornerRadius = self.RcCornerRad;
        l_shadHeight = self.RcShadHeight;
        l_textYOffset = self.RcTextYOffset;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've also tried the following methods

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setSizingClassValues];
}

- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection
{
    [super traitCollectionDidChange:previousTraitCollection];
    [self setSizingClassValues];
}

- (void)updateConstraints
{
    [self setSizingClassValues];
    [super updateConstraints];
}
```

.

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        [self setSizingClassValues];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Run time, loading from xib.
}

- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder
{
    [super prepareForInterfaceBuilder];
    // Design time.
    [self setSizingClassValues];
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried to do what you're doing, but it certainly sounds like a good place for problems to surface, since IB previews and IBInspectables are kind of primitive. If you have a simple use case / demo project, file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Yeah, if it is a bug. Any suggestions on a workaround? Although this is a workaround from not having sizing classes on ibinspectable properties.

Comment: Well, I don't really see what there is that you need to work around. The preview / display in IB is not very important, and you can always set property values in code, so you're not really having any problem for your actual app.

Comment: what setSizingClassValues method is doing? Why draw rect do nothing (just changing local values)?

Comment: As shown above setSizingClassValues sets variables based on the sizing class. Drawrect then uses these variables to draw.

Comment: Really I can see that draw rect sets variables instead and there is no implementation of setSizingClassValues in your question...

Comment: Oh sorry yes, I had the traits stuff in that function which is shown in drawrect above

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the code and for me it seems like it is working code.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Could you be a bit more descriptive?  I think it is a bug with Xcode it self.  Note that the first one looks right.  I understand if I am not descriptive enough but could you possibly tell me what you are trying to do?  Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: It looks like a bug apple have marked it as a duplicate. I'm trying to use the trait collection to perform conditional code which is displayed in IB and IB preview.